# Is the Passive voice of the sentence is grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar

Active voice -The teacher taught her English.

Passive voice-English was taught her by the teacher.

Should i use 'taught to' instead of 'taught'

Comment: The sentence is only marginally acceptable but it's found and some speakers use it.

Comment: "She was taught English by her teacher" would be my choice.